# ¿Cómo pasar datos json a chart.js?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, chart.js

Ya tengo preparada mi consulta para tener ventas por dia, por mes y por año, ahora esta general pero solo es de agregar condición `WHERE` o dejar individual la consulta por dia, mes y año:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT YEAR(order_date) AS year_report,
                            MONTHNAME(order_date) AS month_report,
                            sum(quantity) AS quantity,
                            sum(price) AS price,
                            order_date
                        FROM tbl_order
                        WHERE id_manager=6
                        GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTHNAME(order_date)
                        ORDER BY YEAR(order_date), MONTHNAME(order_date)");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$dateArray = [];//array();
$dateArray2 = [];
$stmt->bind_result(
    $year_report,
    $month_report,
    $quantity,
    $price,
    $order_date
);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $dateArray[] = $order_date;
    $dateArray2[] = $month_report;
}
```

Y manualmente ya he preparado mi gráfica usando la librería `chartjs`:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 3.9.1-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="chartBox">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <button onclick="timeFrame(this)" value="day">Day</button>
    <button onclick="timeFrame(this)" value="week">Week</button>
    <button onclick="timeFrame(this)" value="month">Month</button>
</div>
<script>
    const day = [
        { x: Date.parse('2021-11-01 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 18 },
        { x: Date.parse('2021-11-02 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 12 },
        { x: Date.parse('2021-11-03 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 1 }
    ];
    const week = [
        { x: Date.parse('2021-10-31 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 18 },
        { x: Date.parse('2021-11-02 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 87 },
        { x: Date.parse('2021-11-03 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 10 }
    ];
    const month = [
        { x: Date.parse('2021-10-31 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 18 },
        { x: Date.parse('2021-11-02 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 87 },
        { x: Date.parse('2021-12-03 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 10 }
    ];

    console.log(day);
    // setup 
    const data = {
      //labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: day,
        //data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'month'
                }
            },
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
    function timeFrame(period) {
        //console.log(period)
        //console.log(period.value)
        if(period.value == 'day') {
            myChart.config.options.scales.x.time.unit = period.value;
            myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = day;
        }
        if(period.value == 'week') {
            myChart.config.options.scales.x.time.unit = period.value;
            myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = week;
        }
        if(period.value == 'month') {
            myChart.config.options.scales.x.time.unit = period.value;
            myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = month;
        }
        myChart.update();
    }
</script>
```

Lo que no entiendo es cómo puedo pasar mis datos `json` de mi consulta a estos parámetros de `JavaScript` que la funcionalidad `chart.js` espera:

```
const day = [
    { x: Date.parse('2021-11-01 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 18 },
    { x: Date.parse('2021-11-02 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 12 },
    { x: Date.parse('2021-11-03 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 1 }
];
const week = [
    { x: Date.parse('2021-10-31 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 18 },
    { x: Date.parse('2021-11-02 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 87 },
    { x: Date.parse('2021-11-03 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 10 }
];
const month = [
    { x: Date.parse('2021-10-31 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 18 },
    { x: Date.parse('2021-11-02 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 87 },
    { x: Date.parse('2021-12-03 00:00:00 GMT+0800'), y: 10 }
];
```

¿Me pueden explicar cómo pasar dicha información a mi gráfico?

---

## Actualización

Realizando intentos he realizado la siguiente modificaciones, aún estoy muy lejos de conseguir los datos de: `const day, const week, const month` pero de la siguiente manera he obtenido en la parte inferior los meses:

```
const dateArray = <?php echo json_encode($dateArray); ?>;
const dateChart = dateArray.map((day, index) => {
    let dayjs = new Date(day);
    console.log(dayjs);
    return dayjs.setHours(0,0,0,0);
})

//console.log(dateChart);
//console.log(day);
// setup 
const data = {
  //labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
  //labels: dateChart,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Weekly Sales',
    data: dateChart,
```

Es decir prácticamente tengo los datos `x:` faltarían los datos `y:` curiosamente probé lo siguiente pero no funcionó:

```
data: [dateChart, 10, 12, 18, 20],
```

> Nota:los datos en `y:` van las cantidades de artículos vendidos de la variable `$quantity` adicional me gustaría agregar los ingresos totales que se los obtiene de la variable `$price`

Answer (score 0):

En cualquier lenguaje la clave está en recorrer con for el request. Si decidimos crear como los datos a usar day_report y price, creamos 2 vectores, los cuales lo llenamos con un for y asignamos como atributos de chartJS:

```js
var outcome; 
$.getJSON('url', function(json) {
    outcome = json; 
});

var dias = [];
var precios = [];

for (var i in outcome) {
    dias.push(outcome[i].day_report);
    precios.push(outcome[i].price);
}

const data = {
  labels: dias
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Weekly Sales',
    data: precios,
    //data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};
```

Comment: En la parte de javascript donde realizo el echo json?

Comment: La parte del php está bien, todo mi código es la parte Javscript, si esa tu pregunta, cuando se hace la consulta con el método: 'getJSON' ya todo se manipula con el Json.

Comment: Me di cuenta que con esas condiciones no va a funcionar los filtros ya que en el `labels` no se pasa nada, solo en ,`data`

Comment: Pero como declare dos vectores dias[ ], precio[ ], puedes poner el valor que quieras y de la data en outsome, el request que llega de php puedes elegir que valores y poner y agregar a cualquier vector.

Comment: es decir que debe ser `data: precios, dias,` porque aquí es donde se deben ir los datos, porque sino es así entonces tocaría modificar el código php

Comment: Exacto, depende que campos devuelve el código php, tambien existen otras gráficas que pueden visualizarse con mas variables, tomalo que labels es como x y data como y.

Comment: Realmente solo serían dos datos, las fechas y las cantidades adicional si es que se puede los precios

Comment: Te recomiendo que lo hagas primero en Excel, para que veas cuantas variables y datos te permite la gráfica, porque algunas gráficas permiten más o menos datos para exponer, así sabes si elegir barras, tortas, anillos, áreas, etc.